# command in rust does not get called via invoke, no error message

Tags: javascript, rust, tauri

I've got 3 commands i am calling from the front end, 2 of them work perfectly, the third does not.
The issue lies with the function tournament_search

main.rs:

```
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .manage(ApiKey {key: Default::default()})
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![set_api_key, check_connection, tournament_search])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

#[tauri::command]
fn set_api_key(key: String , state: State<ApiKey>){
    let mut api_key = state.key.lock().unwrap();
    *api_key = key;
}


#[tauri::command]
async fn check_connection(api_key: State<'_, ApiKey>) -> Result<bool, ()> {
    let key = api_key.key.lock().unwrap().clone();
    let res = Client::new().get(API_URL).bearer_auth(key).send().await.unwrap().text().await.unwrap();
    let json: Value = serde_json::from_str(res.as_str()).unwrap();
    match json["success"].as_bool() {
        Some(_x) => Ok(false),
        None => Ok(true)
    }
}


#[tauri::command]
async fn tournament_search(search_string: String, api_key: State<'_, ApiKey>) -> Result<&str, ()> {
    println!("test: {}", search_string);
    let key = api_key.key.lock().unwrap().clone();
    let mut query: String = String::new();
    query.push_str("query($name:String){tournaments(query:{filter:{name:$name}}){nodes{name,slug,id}}},{$name:");
    query.push_str(search_string.as_str());
    query.push_str("}");
    let res = Client::new().get(API_URL).bearer_auth(key).body(query).send().await.unwrap().text().await.unwrap();
    println!("{}", res);

    Ok("")
}
```

index.js:

```
const { invoke } = window.__TAURI__.tauri

window.addEventListener("load", (ev) => {
    let test = document.getElementById("test");
    let apiKey = document.getElementById("apiKey");
    let tournamentSearch = document.getElementById("tournamentSearch");
    let tourneyList = document.getElementById("tourneyList");

    apiKey.addEventListener("input", (ev) => {
        invoke("set_api_key", {key: apiKey.value});
        invoke("check_connection").then((res) => {
            if(res){
                tournamentSearch.disabled = false;            
            }else{
                tournamentSearch.disabled = true;
            }
        });
    });

    tournamentSearch.addEventListener("input", (ev) => {
        test.innerText = "e";
        invoke('tournament_search', {search_string: tournamentSearch.value}).then((res) => {
            test.innerText = res;
        });
    });


});
```

Already looked for zero width characters, whether the event get's called in js etc. The issue is just that the function is not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd only see an error message by adding a `.catch()` to the invoke call.

Anyawy, the issue here is that Tauri converts command arguments to camelCase on the rust side (to match the JS default) so it would be `{ searchString: tournamentSearch.value }` instead.

If you'd prefer snake_case instead, you can tell Tauri to use that for arguments by changing the command like this:

```rs
#[tauri::command(rename_all = "snake_case")]
```

Comment: Well that's silly. But thank you